# How can i use div bookmarks without covering part of the div during navigation?

Tags: html, css

I use 'id' html tags to navigate through my one-page template:

```
<article class="item leading-1 clearfix" id="services">
    <h1>What can i do for you</h1>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Article text</p>
</article>
```

When i click a menu item, the page goes to the div described by the id.

However, the navigation bar covers part of the div making it difficult to read.

[image]

Is it possible to make the navigation jump to just before the div?

Comment: Maybe add some padding to the `div` in css?

Comment: @GluePear - won't that increase the spacing between articles? I prefer not to do that

Comment: @GluePear - i decided to indeed add padding which solved the problem